# Calling an MS SQL Stored Procedure in C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, winapi, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm writing an application that connects to a stored procedure on an MS SQL (2012) Server. The procedure is for inserting data to the database. I'm having real trouble understanding how to define the connection to the stored procedure, bind variables to the parameters and associating those parameters with the variables in the stored procedure. I've spent a few days wading through MSDN reading the APIs and trying to follow examples on here, but there seem to be so many ways of doing this that I can't see the 'wood for the trees'. I think I have the basic structure in place, but I'm falling down on the detail.

Below is the code I have so far. I've omitted the database connection code for simplicity. The function is part of a class 'rigDatabase' which has private members for the various SQL handles.

The main issue I'm having is with the calls to SQLSetDescField. Based on the documentation and examples provided by Microsoft, these calls should work, but instead return HY092 - "Invalid attribute/option identifier". This is what I need help with. Recently I tried logging the output from the ODBC Driver manager to see if that shed any light on the matter. The output to one of the calls to SQLSetDescField can be seen below the Stored Procedure definition.

NB: I haven't yet tried the simpler method of embedding the SQL in the C. I'm trying to interface with existing infrastructure (the Stored Proc).

```
SQLRETURN rigDatabase::send_SQL(const char* filename, 
                                const char* extn, 
                                const char* path, 
                                DWORD& fSize, 
                                const char* rigName, 
                                FILETIME& created,
                                const char* notes) {
    SQLHDESC hIpd = NULL;
    SQLINTEGER    PartIDInd = 0;

SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT datetime2;
    datetime2.year = fileDate.wYear;
    datetime2.month = fileDate.wMonth;
    datetime2.day = fileDate.wDay;
    datetime2.hour = fileDate.wHour;
    datetime2.minute = fileDate.wMinute;
    datetime2.second = fileDate.wSecond;
    datetime2.fraction = fileDate.wMilliseconds;

    retcode = SQLPrepareA(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLCHAR*)"{call insertTestRigDataTest(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}", SQL_NTS);

    retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,           SQL_CHAR,           FILENAME_MAX,   0, (SQLPOINTER)filename,    0, NULL);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,           SQL_CHAR,           MAX_PATH,       0, (SQLPOINTER)path,        0, NULL);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,           SQL_CHAR,           BUF_SIZE,       0, (SQLPOINTER)rigName,     0, NULL);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 4, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG,          SQL_INTEGER,        0,              0, (SQLPOINTER)fSize,       0, &PartIDInd);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 5, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,           SQL_CHAR,           4,              0, (SQLPOINTER)extn,        0, NULL);

    retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 6, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, sizeof(SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT), 0, &datetime2, 0, NULL);
    retcode = SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 7, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,           SQL_CHAR,           4000,       0, (SQLPOINTER)notes,       0, NULL);

    retcode = SQLGetStmtAttrA(sqlStmtHandle, SQL_ATTR_IMP_PARAM_DESC, &hIpd, 0, 0);

    // All calls to SQLSetDescField below return -1
            //  SQLGetDiagRecA returns "Invalid attribute/option identifier"
    retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 1, SQL_DESC_NAME, "@Filename", SQL_NTS);
    retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 2, SQL_DESC_NAME, "@Path", SQL_NTS);
    retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 3, SQL_DESC_NAME, "@Rigname", SQL_NTS);
    retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 4, SQL_DESC_NAME, "@Size", SQL_NTS);
    retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 5, SQL_DESC_NAME, "@Extn", SQL_NTS);
    retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 6, SQL_DESC_NAME, "@Created", SQL_NTS);
    retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 7, SQL_DESC_NAME, "@Notes", SQL_NTS);

    retcode = SQLExecute(sqlStmtHandle);    

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Function to convert from FILETIME to int64
unsigned __int64 FILETIME_to_int64( const FILETIME& ac_FileTime ) {
    ULARGE_INTEGER    lv_Large;

    lv_Large.LowPart = ac_FileTime.dwLowDateTime;
    lv_Large.HighPart = ac_FileTime.dwHighDateTime;

    return lv_Large.QuadPart;
}
```

**MS SQL Stored Procedure**

```
USE [TestRigDataTest]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insertTestRigDataTest]    Script Date: 16/10/2018 10:14:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertTestRigDataTest] 
(
    @fileName   nvarchar(255),
    @path       nvarchar(255),
    @rigName    nvarchar(255),
    @size       [numeric](18, 0),
    @extn       nvarchar(255),
    @created    [datetime],
    @notes      nvarchar(4000) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @id int
    declare @tmpNotes nvarchar(4000)

    set @tmpNotes=''

    select @id=id,@tmpNotes=notes from [TestRigDataTest].[dbo].[RigData]
        where
            [Filename]=@filename and
            [Path]=@Path and
            [Size]=@Size and
            [Extension]=@Extn and
            [created]=@created

    if @@rowcount=0
        begin
            INSERT INTO [TestRigDataTest].[dbo].[RigData] (
                   [Filename], [Path], [Rigname] ,[UploadDate] ,[Size] ,[Extension]  ,[created]  ,[notes]
                   )
                VALUES (
                   @fileName, @path, @rigName, getdate(), @size, @extn, @created, @notes
                   )
        end
    else
        begin
            if @notes != ''
                begin
                    update [TestRigDataTest].[dbo].[RigData] set [notes]=@tmpNotes  + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + @notes
                    where id=@id
            end
        end
END
```

**ODBC Driver Manager Partial Trace Log:**
NB: SQLSetDescField is #defined to SQLSetDescFieldW

```
AirCatFeeder    26f0-1e50   ENTER SQLSetDescFieldW 
    SQLHDESC            0x00000000004CB9E8
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 
    SQLSMALLINT               1011 <SQL_DESC_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER          0x000000013FBA15EC [      -3] "??h\ 0"
    SQLINTEGER                  -3 

AirCatFeeder    26f0-1e50   ENTER SQLSetDescField 
    SQLHDESC            0x00000000004CB9E8
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 
    SQLSMALLINT               1011 <SQL_DESC_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER          0x000000013FBA15EC [      -3] "@Path\ 0"
    SQLINTEGER                  -3 

AirCatFeeder    26f0-1e50   EXIT  SQLSetDescField  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
    SQLHDESC            0x00000000004CB9E8
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 
    SQLSMALLINT               1011 <SQL_DESC_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER          0x000000013FBA15EC [      -3] "@Path\ 0"
    SQLINTEGER                  -3 

    DIAG [HY092] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid attribute/option identifier (0) 

AirCatFeeder    26f0-1e50   EXIT  SQLSetDescFieldW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
    SQLHDESC            0x00000000004CB9E8
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 
    SQLSMALLINT               1011 <SQL_DESC_NAME>
    SQLPOINTER          0x000000013FBA15EC [      -3] "??h\ 0"
    SQLINTEGER                  -3 

    DIAG [HY092] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid attribute/option identifier (0)
```

Comment: Why did you skip argument 6?  Also, use [SQLGetDiagRec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdiagrec-function?view=sql-server-2017) when a returns a failure code.

Comment: Well spotted Paul. I'd removed an unneeded parameter and forgot to update the numbering. I've corrected the code above, but still have the same issue.

Comment: Added SQLGetDiagRec to the code. SQLBindParameter call #6 returns "Invalid precision value". So this is trying to munge a ulong int into an SQL type of datetime. Investigating...

Comment: The SQLSetDescField calls return "Invalid attribute/option identifier".

Comment: Those are the immediate issues.  Will need to do some more experimentation to get the reason for the error you're getting (been a while since I did this stuff).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the use of wide strings. `SQLSetDescField` #defines to `SQLSetDescFieldW`, but the string literal was not marked as being a wide string. I was missing the 'L' before the string definietion. A sample of the correct code is below.

```
retcode = SQLSetDescField(hIpd, 1, SQL_DESC_NAME, L"@filename", SQL_NTS);
```

Interesting to note that I tried using demo code from MSDN, which is based on wide strings, but their own code featured this error. Very frustrating when you're trying to learn, but perhaps they're being like the old meccano kits - putting in deliberate errors. I certainly won't be forgetting this lesson!